# I cannot find my VT-X in my BIOS

Tags: bios, acer-aspire, vt-x

I currently using an Acer Aspire 5742G Laptop. It has an I3 processing core and according to intel, it supports virtualization. However, i was suppose to enable it right now for my android emulator but i couldn't find my VT-x in my laptop bios. Please help how will i be able to activate it if the feature is hidden in bios?

Comment: Did you do anything odd, like read the manual? :)

Comment: @Dave [Ain't nobody got time for that](http://youtu.be/FIKI7ArSvlY?t=17s). ;)

Answer (score 3):

Acer **usually** disables this option on ther mid-tier laptops.

First of all try a BIOS update, later versions may have it enabled.

If you want it enabled even if the manufacturer doesn't want you to, you can probably flash a modified BIOS, but this is VERY RISKY BUSINESS. You will probably void your warranty, may end up with broken notebook, get yourself a virus and whatnot...

If you want to give it a try there are [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09GZtiK4OrI) video guides available, but make sure you know what you are doing.